# jQuery focus not working on TextBox in jQuery ModalDailog box

Tags: jquery, focus, bootstrap-modal

As description suggest, I click on a button on my form and that trigger a `Modal Dialog` box to appear with couple of textboxes. What i want is to focus on first textbox in my form. In my case, i know its `Id` but the code doesn't seems to focus on textbox

**Solution Tried**

1) `$('#modalId').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#TextBoxId").focus();
    });`

2) `$("#TextBoxId").focus();` on document ready

I can debug in firebug and see it does get called but doesn't focus.

Anyone came across this problem

Thanks,

Comment: Please post your HTML. Also, try console logging your `$("#TextBoxId")` selection to see what it's targeting.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check this code**

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#txtfocus").focus();

});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div>Second text box is focused with focus method</div> 
<input type="text" id="txtfocus2"><br/>

This text box is set focused: <input type="text" id="txtfocus">

 </body>

</html>
```

***Code is highlighting but you are not able to recognize it, please use some border once you are highlighting.***

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

If you can post your code it will be easier to find your specific problem

http://jsfiddle.net/DrLazer/MqJX5/2/

HTML

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
First Text Box:<br/>
<input type="text" id="txtfcs"><br/>
<br/><br/>
Second Text Box:<br/> 
<input type="text" id="txtfcs2">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtfcs2").focus();
});
```

Comment: which browser are you using DrLazer to test. I am using Firefox and your fiddle doesn't work.